# Set the dimension for simpleRNN (Please provide data which shares the same first dimension)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to test the `simpleRNN`

`stft_librosa` is numpy data `(257, 958)`

My Idea is put sliced `(10,958)` for input and get `(1,958)` for output.

```
epochs = 10
batch = 24
model.add(
    SimpleRNN(1, activation=None, input_shape=(958,1), return_sequences=True)
)
model.add(Dense(1, activation="linear")) 
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer="sgd")
print(model.summary())

for num in range(0, epochs):
    print(num + 1, '/', epochs, ' start')
    
    for i,data in enumerate(stft_librosa):
        if i == 0:continue
        in_data = stft_librosa[i - 1]
        out_data = stft_librosa[i]
        model.fit(in_data, out_data, epochs=1, shuffle=False, batch_size=batch)
        model.reset_states()
    print(num+1, '/', epochs, ' epoch is done!')

model.save('/data/mymodel')
```

There comes error like this, how should I fix it??

```
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 9
  y sizes: 958
Please provide data which shares the same first dimension.
```

model.summary() is here.

```
Output Shape              Param #   

simple_rnn (SimpleRNN)       (None, 9, 958)            1836486   

dense (Dense)                (None, 9, 1)              959       

Total params: 1,837,445
Trainable params: 1,837,445
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `input_shape=(9,958)` is wrong (this is after you have edited the question). Correct one is `input_shape=(958, 1)` - the one that you have in your original question.(*please, don't edit your questions like that, you have changed both the model, by adding the Dense layer, and the error by changing the input shape*).

The original error, before you updated the question, is due to the incorrect shape of the inputs that you are feeding into the model. This model expects 3-dimensional input - the first one being the batch size but you are feeding it a single sample at a time.

Here is how you can reshape your data.

```
x = stft_librosa[:-1, :].reshape((-1, 958, 1))
y = stft_librosa[1:, :].reshape((-1, 958, 1))
print(x.shape, y.shape)

# ((256, 958, 1), (256, 958, 1))
```

This will shift `y` one index ahead and remove the last index from `x`.

Once you have that, you can just call the `fit` method once without the need for that loop.

```
model = Sequential([
    SimpleRNN(1, activation=keras.activations.linear, input_shape=(958, 1), return_sequences=True),
    Dense(1, activation=keras.activations.linear)
])
model.compile(optimizer=SGD(lr=0.000001), loss=keras.losses.MeanSquaredError())

model.fit(x, y, epochs=5, batch_size=24)

#Epoch 1/5
#11/11 [==============================] - 3s 266ms/step - loss: 2.8277
#Epoch 2/5
#11/11 [==============================] - 3s 266ms/step - loss: 2.0028
#Epoch 3/5
#11/11 [==============================] - 2s 224ms/step - loss: 1.8698
#Epoch 4/5
#11/11 [==============================] - 3s 229ms/step - loss: 1.7877
#Epoch 5/5
#11/11 [==============================] - 2s 226ms/step - loss: 1.7307
```

*I suggest you revert the edit to your question because the original code made more sense than the current one*

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer is very helpful to me. I miss understood many points for multi dimension `RNN`. My training model works.

Answer (score 0):

The first dimension is batch dimension. It should be the same for input and output.

Try this:

```
    in_data = stft_librosa[i - 1][tf.newaxis, :]
    out_data = stft_librosa[i][tf.newaxis, :]
```